# GUPC Vs Berkeley UPC

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, gnu, hpc, upc

I am trying to use UPC on a cluster with CPU/GPU hybrid nodes. Environment is Ubuntu 12.04. I am new to UPC and I found 2 versions of UPC: GNU UPC(GUPC) and Berkeley UPC. When I looked for Linux versions, only GNU GCC had a compiler for linux. So is there a difference between Berkeley and GNU version in terms of the UPC libraries? Or is GNU UPC based on Berkley UPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that the only UPC translator for Linux is the GNU one. Berkeley UPC also lists Linux as a [supported platform](http://upc.lbl.gov/download/source.shtml#translator) (and I personally testify that it does support Linux).

Both translators (as current UPC compilers actually use an intermediate source-to-source translation) use different runtime libraries with GUPC also being able to [use the Berkeley UPCR runtime](http://www.gccupc.org/gnu-upc-info/gnu-upc-with-berkeley-upcr-runtime) instead. UPCR is more capable than the runtime that ships with GUPC in terms of transports supported and synchronisation primitives provided.

Comment: Yeah you are right... I could build the source on Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks